# How to add two function on one onlick?

Tags: dom, simple-html-dom

> This already work fine for the first element

```
 onclick="document.getElementById('event').setAttribute('value', 'MD')
```

> But I want to add the second element to be affected on the onclick.

```
 <div class="item" id="select_MD" onclick="document.getElementById('event').setAttribute('value', 'MD'), document.getElementById('letter-bg',).css('background', 'url(/images/giftcard-events/HBD.jpg)')">
    <div class="box border">
        <img src="{{ url('/images/giftcard-events/MD.jpg') }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

> First Element

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="event" name="event" value="">
</div>
```

> Second element

```
<div id="letter-bg"></div
```

Comment: Create a function that does both actions. Call that function in your onclick event.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in by create the function that do both like this

```
onclick="function Click() {
document.getElementById('event').setAttribute('value', 'MD');
document.getElementById('letter-bg',).css('background', 'url(/images/giftcard-events/HBD.jpg)');
}
Click();"
```

Or you can create the function on a script tag then call it in the onlick